# How to allign 3 images in one row?

Tags: css, wordpress, image, row, inline

I have 3 payment logos in my footer that want to have centered and aligned in one row.
How to do that?

```css
sliki {
  text-align: justify;
}

sliki img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 7px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  float: right;
}

sliki:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliki">
  <img src="//ssif1.globalsign.com/SiteSeal/siteSeal/siteSeal/siteSealImage.do?p1=www.prozis.com&amp;p2=SZ90-35&amp;p3=image&amp;p4=en&amp;p5=V0023&amp;p6=S001&amp;p7=https&amp;deterDn=" alt="" />
  <img src="//static.sscontent.com/prozis/contents/logotypes/visa_96x56_675_17096.png" alt="" width="48" />
  <img src="//static.sscontent.com/prozis/contents/logotypes/mastercard_96x56_676_17097.png" alt="" width="48" height="28" />
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ebL584w/).
[See the footer on my site.](https://nutrifit-shop.com/).

Comment: Add some code for things you've attempted and ideally a jsfiddle.net link or something. Without any code it's hard to say what you're doing wrong.

Comment: use `display: inline-block;`

Comment: This is JSfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/5ebL584w/  Working OK, but on my site is not alligned. What is problem ?

Comment: also, you don't have dot(.) in front of your classes in css

Comment: text-align and then float do not mix. , sliki is a class and should be written .sliki . Also, text-align:justify has no effect on the last line(even if also first), use or complete with text-align-last https://jsfiddle.net/5ebL584w/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text-align` and then `float` do not mix.

`sliki` is a class and should be written `.sliki` .

Also, `text-align:justify` has no effect on the last line(even if also first), use or complete with `text-align-last` https://jsfiddle.net/5ebL584w/1/ to avoid using an extra pseudo

```css
.sliki {
  text-align: justify;
  /* and instead :after 
  text-align-last:justify;
  */
}

.sliki img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 7px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  /*float: right;*/
}

.sliki:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliki">
  <img src="//ssif1.globalsign.com/SiteSeal/siteSeal/siteSeal/siteSealImage.do?p1=www.prozis.com&amp;p2=SZ90-35&amp;p3=image&amp;p4=en&amp;p5=V0023&amp;p6=S001&amp;p7=https&amp;deterDn=" alt="" />
  <img src="//static.sscontent.com/prozis/contents/logotypes/visa_96x56_675_17096.png" alt="" width="48" />
  <img src="//static.sscontent.com/prozis/contents/logotypes/mastercard_96x56_676_17097.png" alt="" width="48" height="28" />
</div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last

> **This is an experimental technology**
>
> Because this technology's specification has not stabilized, check the compatibility table for usage in various browsers. Also note that the syntax and behavior of an experimental technology is subject to change in future versions of browsers as the specification changes.
>
> The text-align-last CSS property describes how the last line of a block or a line, right before a forced line break, is aligned.

Answer (score 1):

you where missing the '.' in front of your class names in your css file and I added a few class name to your image.

```css
.sliki {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.sliki img.credit {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48px;
  height: 28px;
  padding: 7px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

img.secure {
  width: 90px;
  height: 35px;
}

sliki:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48px;
  height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliki">

  <img class="secure" src="//ssif1.globalsign.com/SiteSeal/siteSeal/siteSeal/siteSealImage.do?p1=www.prozis.com&amp;p2=SZ90-35&amp;p3=image&amp;p4=en&amp;p5=V0023&amp;p6=S001&amp;p7=https&amp;deterDn=" alt="" />

  <img class="credit" src="//static.sscontent.com/prozis/contents/logotypes/visa_96x56_675_17096.png" alt="" width="48" />
  <img class="credit" src="//static.sscontent.com/prozis/contents/logotypes/mastercard_96x56_676_17097.png" alt="" width="48" height="28" />

</div>
```